# lower the minimum resolution of any window

Tags: windows, resolution, gaming

I set up a market in a game and I no longer need to look at the game screen. Even if I lower the image quality, the game uses too many resources. Is there a way or program to set the game's resolution to a lower level (e.g. 100x100) than what's in the settings tab to reduce resource usage?

Comment: In my experience, screen resolution does not affect CPU.  I have 4 different resolutions running and CPU is roughly zero.  Look to your game for CPU issues.